# Rollback is not working for transaction using Jdo in GAE, though code is executing successfully

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, rollback, datastore

Transaction is being rollbacked successfully as reflected by the code.However the operation which are performed in transaction were not reflected to the database and were not rolledback in non-committed active state of tx i.e. when records are deleled using tx(Transaction) of PMF and DynaPMF rollback for undo the operation does not works.

Here PMF, DynaPMF refer to 2 distinct PersistanceMangerFactory for two different database

```
    if (isTransactionLocal || (PMF.getTransactionCounter() > 0 || DynaPMF.getTransactionCounter() > 0)) {
                //tx.rollback();
                if(PMF.getPerThreadTransaction()!=null){
                    tx=PMF.getPerThreadTransaction();
                    System.err.println(tx.hashCode()+"transaction thread is Alive =>"+tx.isActive());
                    if(tx.isActive()){
                        tx.rollback();
                        System.err.println("rollback for tx = "+tx.hashCode()+" done .");
                    }
                }

                if(DynaPMF.getPerThreadTransaction()!=null){
                    tx=DynaPMF.getPerThreadTransaction();
                    System.err.println(tx.hashCode()+"transaction thread is Alive =>"+tx.isActive());
                    if(tx.isActive()){
                        tx.rollback();
                        System.err.println("rollback for tx = "+tx.hashCode()+" done .");
                    }

                }
PMF.setPerThreadTransaction(null);
DynaPMF.setPerThreadTransaction(null);
```

Output:

```
1861140113transaction thread is Alive =>true
rollback for tx = 1861140113 done .
336180090transaction thread is Alive =>true
rollback for tx = 336180090 done .
```

It is showing in code that rollback occurred successfully, but not reflecting in database.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per JDO rollback can be performed only on those objects which have persistance-clean state during JDO Lifecycle as can be seen from 
https://db.apache.org/jdo/state_transition.html
and rollback from other state cannot be reflected to datastore.